# _tkinter.TclError and Terminator issue

Tags: canvas, turtle-graphics, screensaver, terminator

I've written the following code to be a screensaver, a little rough, but its a start. I can kind of get full screen but the issue I run into is when I close the app, I get the turtle terminator error. The whole point is to kill the app at any time in the process without throwing an error. Kind of like the old 3d pipes screensaver from the 90s. I have it convert ed to an '.scr' file, but I can only click the x or alt-f4 to terminate and it pops the error message. Can someone help, I feel like I'm right there.

```
import turtle as t

from turtle import Screen

import random

tim = t.Turtle()

tim.ht()

t.colormode(255)

tim.speed(6)

screen = Screen()

screenTk = screen.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()

screenTk.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

color_list = [(54, 108, 149), (225, 201, 108), (134, 85, 58), (224, 141, 62),
              (197, 144, 171), (143, 180, 206), (137, 82, 106), (210, 90, 68), (188, 78, 122),
              (69, 101, 86), (132, 183, 132), (65, 156, 86), (137, 132, 74), (48, 155, 195), (183, 191, 202),
              (58, 47, 41), (47, 59, 96), (38, 44, 64), (106, 46, 54), (41, 55, 48), (12, 104, 95),
              (118, 125, 145), (182, 194, 199), (54, 45, 52)]

running = True

while running:

    tim.pu()

    tim.setpos(-825, -450)

    for i in range(7):

        for _ in range(12):

            tim.dot(100, random.choice(color_list))

            tim.fd(150)

        y = ((i + 1) * 150) – 450

        tim.setpos(-825, y)

    tim.clear()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem appears to be this line:

```
y = ((i + 1) * 150) – 450
```

The subtraction sign isn't the correct character, it's some sort of Unicode look-alike not an actual `-` sign.  But there's a bigger problem:

If this were corrected, and the program ran, you'd lock yourself out of your computer.  The `screen.exitonclick()` is never reached, so you can't click your way out.  Even if reached, you'd still be locked out as the click events have no opportunity to reach the event handler as you're constantly drawing.

This turns out to be a trickier problem than I first guessed.  I've done a complete rework of your code, turning it inside out, so that the event handler is looped in for *every* dot.  That way, when you click on the window, it will immediately quit and go away.  (I defined my own `exitonclick()` functionality to avoid the error messages by being heartless.)

```
import sys
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

color_list = [
    (54, 108, 149), (225, 201, 108), (134, 85, 58), (224, 141, 62),
    (197, 144, 171), (143, 180, 206), (137, 82, 106), (210, 90, 68),
    (188, 78, 122), (69, 101, 86), (132, 183, 132), (65, 156, 86),
    (137, 132, 74), (48, 155, 195), (183, 191, 202), (58, 47, 41),
    (47, 59, 96), (38, 44, 64), (106, 46, 54), (41, 55, 48),
    (12, 104, 95), (118, 125, 145), (182, 194, 199), (54, 45, 52)
]

def draw_column(row=0, column=11):
    turtle.dot(100, choice(color_list))
    turtle.forward(150)

    if column > 0:
        screen.ontimer(lambda: draw_column(row, column - 1))
    else:
        screen.ontimer(lambda: draw_row(row + 1))

def draw_row(row=7):
    if row == 7:
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.setpos(-825, -450)
        screen.ontimer(draw_column)
    else:
        y = (row * 150) - 450
        turtle.setposition(-825, y)
        screen.ontimer(lambda: draw_column(row))

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

window = screen.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

draw_row()

def exitHeartlessly(x, y):
    sys.exit(0)

screen.onclick(exitHeartlessly)

screen.mainloop()
```

In theory, `screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)` should give you the same result as the `attributes('-fullscreen', True)` but in practice it doesn't so nice work finding a work-around.

Comment: I always have a big problem pasting my code in to here from pycharm. It junks up the characters and gives an error about things not being tabbed correctly. I'll give this a shot and see what happens.